# Object is flickering while moving in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm trying to create a game using pygame here when object is moving it is flickering I tried screen.fill () and update () but nothing worked.
This question may be repeated but answers related to this question wasn't worked

````
import pygame, sys,random


def create_block():
    global rand_block
    rand_block_rect=rand_block.get_rect(topleft = (random.choice(blck_pos),-20))
    return rand_block_rect

def move_block(blocks):
    for block in blocks:
        block.centery+=5
    return blocks
def draw_block(blocks):
    for block in blocks:
        screen.blit(rand_block,block)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 600))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
clock=pygame.time.Clock()


# blocks
blocks={
    1:pygame.image.load('blocks/BLOCK L.png'),
    2:pygame.image.load('blocks/BLOCK S.png'),
    3:pygame.image.load('blocks/BLOCK M.png'),
    }
blck_array=[blocks[1],blocks[2],blocks[3]]
blck_pos=[3,47,190,250,357]

block_list=[]

SPAWNPIPE=pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWNPIPE,1200)

bal_x=0
loop = True

while loop:
    rand_block = random.choice(blck_array)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==SPAWNPIPE:
            block_list.append(create_block())
            print(block_list)

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    block_list=move_block(block_list)
    draw_block(block_list)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you choose a new random block in every frame. Just choose a new block when a new block is created:

```py
def create_block():
    global rand_block

    rand_block = random.choice(blck_array) # <-- INSERT

    rand_block_rect = rand_block.get_rect(topleft = (random.choice(blck_pos),-20))
    return rand_block_rect
```

```py
while loop:
  
    # rand_block = random.choice(blck_array) <-- DELETE

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==SPAWNPIPE:
            block_list.append(create_block())
            print(block_list)

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    block_list=move_block(block_list)
    draw_block(block_list)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```